# Why do i get 401 unauthorised even though credentials are correct?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a get request on an API, that has basic authentication, but even though I have the correct username and password, it won't work.

When I'm trying to reach the API with curl (Linux command) it works fine.

```
curl -u "user:password" -s https://dummy/link/1
```

Do I need to specify that the response must be `enter code here`JSON?

I am using   Maven: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13 dependency

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user","password");
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
    .build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(
    new HttpGet("https://dummy/link/1");
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine()
    .getStatusCode();

if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
  System.out.println(statusCode);
}else{
  System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, which makes me wonder whether you are running the code in your question.

Comment: the link from response and the username and password are an example.

Comment: be sure to use   Maven: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same issue. I noticed my request with curl had the header

`Authorization: Basic base64(username:password)`

that my get request was missing, then i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18109238/5315940) that solved the problem but with a deprecate use of *BasicScheme.authenticate* and finally removed the deprecated part using [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494180/5315940):

```
httpget.setHeader( new BasicScheme(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).authenticate(credentials , httpget, null) );
```

Now it works. Did not check the long way as specified in the first answer.